# What is the point of a * behind a parameter in a function? (Python 2)

Tags: python

In this code, what is the points of the * behind the `args` function?

```
def biggest_number(*args):
  print max(args)
  return max(args)
    
def smallest_number(*args):
  print min(args)
  return min(args)

def distance_from_zero(arg):
  print abs(arg)
  return abs(arg)

biggest_number(-10, -5, 5, 10)
smallest_number(-64, 72, 94, 61, 0)
distance_from_zero(874)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` star before `args` indicates that we're
accepting a list of argument values, which is forwarded
along to the min / max functions.